# Can I embed a 3rd party command line utility in my macOS app and submit it to the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

I am about to submit my app to the Mac App Store. In my app, I use a command line utility that I include in the bundle of my app, in the executables (MacOs) folder. I use this command line utility with NSTask from the app. The command line utility is called optipng, it is open source, and its license allows to distribute it in commercial software, assumed I give credit for this in the about Window. I would like to know, is this allowed on the Mac App Store ? I have signed the command line utility with the same certificate as the app, and I ensure the CLI is closed before quittting my app.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you meet the MAS requirements for executing the code then the answer is *probably* yes - the situation is not that different from using a third-party library.

Why *probably*? I cannot guarantee Apple's decision over any particular app! Your app *sounds* fine.

HTH